# Delegating general class to specific classes

Tags: c#, .net, covariance, contravariance

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IModel
{
    ModelTypes ModelType { get; } // ModelTypes is an enum
}

public interface IModelConverter<T>
{
    byte[] ToBytes(T model);
}
```

Also, I have 3 implementations of `IModel`: `ModelA`,`ModelB`,`ModelC`, and the following classes:

```
public class ModelAConverter : IModelConverter<ModelA>

public class ModelBConverter : IModelConverter<ModelB>

public class ModelCConverter : IModelConverter<ModelC>
```

I want to take an `IModel` and convert it with `ToBytes` method. Obviously, I don't want the caller to know each and every implementation of the converters, so I created the `DelegatingConverter` class:

```
public class DelegatingConverter : IModelConverter<IModel>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<ModelTypes, IModelConverter<IModel>> _modelConverters;

    public DelegatingConverter()
    {
        _modelConverters = new Dictionary<ModelTypes, IModelConverter<IModel>>
        {
            {ModelTypes.TypeA, new ModelAConverter()}, // Argument type ModelAConverter is not assignable to parameter type IModelConverter<IModel>
            {ModelTypes.TypeB, new ModelBConverter()}, // Argument type ModelBConverter is not assignable to parameter type IModelConverter<IModel>
            {ModelTypes.TypeC, new ModelCConverter()}  // Argument type ModelCConverter is not assignable to parameter type IModelConverter<IModel>
        };
    }

    public byte[] ToBytes(IModel model)
    {
        // Here is the delegation..
        return _modelConverters[model.ModelType].ToBytes(model);
    }
}
```

Everything goes great, until I add some converters to the delegating dictionary, `_modelConverters`.

The error is:

> Argument type `ModelXConverter` is not assignable to parameter type
>   `IModelConverter<IModel>`

And I know the solution here should be using covariance on `T` in `IModelConverter`, so the decleration should be:

`public interface IModelConverter<out T>`

When I add it, the following error occurs:

> Parameter must be input-safe. Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T'
>   must be contravariantly valid on IModelConverter.ToBytes(T). 'T' is
>   covariant.

Is there any way to make it better? I know I can make every `ModelConverter` implementation implement `IModelConverter<IModel>`, but then I need an obvious cast in the beginning of each implementation.

Comment: Are your `ModelConverter` classes stateless?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> And I know the solution here should be using covariance on `T` in `IModelConverter`

No, not really. That would only be the case if any *specific* `IModelConverter` could be regarded as a more *general* `IModelConverter` - and that's not the case. If a converter only knows how to convert `ModelB` to bytes, what would you expect it to do with a `ModelC`?

The simplest approach is probably to write something more like this:

```
// This class is general...
public sealed class DelegatingConverter<T> : IModelConverter<IModel>
    where T : IModel
{
    private readonly IModelConverter<T> originalConverter;

    public DelegatingConverter(IModelConverter<T> originalConverter)
    {
        this.originalConverter = originalConverter;
    }

    public byte[] ToBytes(IModel model)
    {
        return originalConverter.ToBytes((T) model);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public sealed class KnownModelConverter : IModelConverter<IModel>
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<ModelTypes, IModelConverter<IModel>>
        = new Dictionary<ModelTypes, IModelConverter<IModel>>
    {
        { ModelTypes.TypeA, new DelegatingConverter<ModelA>(new ModelAConverter()) },
        { ModelTypes.TypeB, new DelegatingConverter<ModelB>(new ModelBConverter()) },
        { ModelTypes.TypeC, new DelegatingConverter<ModelC>(new ModelCConverter()) },
    };

    public byte[] ToBytes(IModel model)
    {
        // Here is the delegation..
        return _modelConverters[model.ModelType].ToBytes(model);
    }
}
```

Basically the key is the cast within `DelegatingConverter<T>` - you need to make sure you only use pass instances of the right type to its `ToBytes` method - but assuming `model.ModelType` is correct, that should be fine. (And if it's not, an exception is probably the right behaviour.)

Comment: A slightly leaner way to do this is to simply have one static `Converter` class with several overloads of `ToBytes` that accept various model types. Now you can just do `Converter.ToBytes(myModel)`.

Comment: @Asad: That assumes the caller knows the type at compile-time though. To make it work when presented with just an `IModel`, you'd need code basically along these lines - or a `switch` or something similar.

Comment: If the caller doesn't know the type at compile time, you can just do `Converter.ToBytes((dynamic) myModel)`, and very elegantly rely on dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @Asad: Using `dynamic` was one of the other options I was considering suggesting - at which point it's perfectly easy to fit into the existing code, and the OP can still implement `IModelConverter<IModel>`.

Comment: Jon, wouldn't it be better if you add a constraint to `DelegatingConverter`. `public sealed class DelegatingConverter<T> : IModelConverter<IModel> where T : IModel`? That will prevent you from making few mistakes at compile time.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yup, will do.

Answer (score -1):

You can type cast it explicitly to avoid the error like

```
public DelegatingConverter()
{
    _modelConverters = new Dictionary<ModelTypes, IModelConverter<IModel>>
    {
        {ModelTypes.TypeA, (IModelConverter<IModel>)new ModelAConverter()},
        {ModelTypes.TypeB, (IModelConverter<IModel>)new ModelBConverter()},
        {ModelTypes.TypeC, (IModelConverter<IModel>)new ModelCConverter()}
    };
}
```

Comment: That will either fail to compile (if the classes are sealed), or the cast will fail at execution time. The converters simply *aren't* `IModelConverter<IModel>`s

Comment: No, I'm not just speculating. If those classes *actually* implemented `IModelConverter<IModel>`, why would the compiler complain in the first place? How would you expect the cast to work?

Comment: @JonSkeet is 100% correct, I tried it and got a runtime error.